# Raspberry Pi autostart python && chromium kioskmode

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, chromium, autostart

Despite the fact that I made this work in the past, I'm unable to get a python command to work in cml and running a chromium kiosk mode at start.

I've tried following lines in.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart 


@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@lxterminal python -m SimpleHTTPServer
@chromium --noerrdialogs --kiosk --icognito  http://localhost:8000/identityloop/face_identity/sketch/
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@point-rpi
#@sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
#@unclutter -idle 0.1 -root
```

all have the same lines of commands in it as is shown above. 
Also made a crontab for the lxterminal that doesn't work.

```
@restart python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

which gives me this error.

```
"/tmp/crontab.1pELjW/crontab":22: bad time specifier
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)
```

I'm unclear in what to do next to make this work.